# Activemerchat paypal integration is giving an error Missing required parameter: ip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used the below code to test my sandbox credentials but am getting the error mentioned please help in resolving the issue

```
> require 'activemerchant'

> @gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.new(
              :login "abc.cc@gmail.com,
              password: "weret43435ersdfdg",
              signature: "ertygdfcf343333@@@@@frfterg")
> purchase = @gateway.purchase((10* 100),
          :ip => '198.16.43.574',
          :currency => "USD",
          :payer_id => "2",
          :token => "dsfddgfdgfdgfdgdf")
```

> When i use the above code in irb am getting the following error
>
> **ArgumentError: Missing required parameter: ip**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvaPb.png)

Comment: Have you looked into it's documentation, https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activemerchant/1.90.0

Answer (score 0):

If you check the source code of `ActiveMerchant` [here](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/paypal.rb#L21), it is expecting 3 params.

```
def purchase(money, credit_card_or_referenced_id, options = {})
  requires!(options, :ip)
  commit define_transaction_type(credit_card_or_referenced_id), build_sale_or_authorization_request('Sale', money, credit_card_or_referenced_id, options)
end
```

First one is the amount of money, second one is the credit card or reference id and the third one is a option, where it is expecting a required ip. As in your method call you are not passing any credit card reference, it's missing the `ip` from the `option` hash.

Comment: Am using different idea from you.

Comment: @ChethanKumarIL If this might help: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activemerchant/1.90.0/ActiveMerchant/Billing/PaypalGateway#purchase-instance_method